# ested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring JPA Repository,Not able to execute query

Here is my java code :

```
public interface TbBamiVacationRepository extends JpaRepository<TbBamiVacation,String>{
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "select user_id,reassign_to from tb_bami_vacation a where to_date1 >=to_date(:toDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date(:toDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') >=from_date and to_date(:toDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') <=to_date1 and user_id='112'",nativeQuery=true)
    List<TbBamiVacation> findReassignedTo( @Param("toDate")String toDate);
                                      //toDate="26-MAR-2017"
}
```

My Logs:

```
Hibernate: select user_id,reassign_to from tb_bami_vacation a where to_date1 >=to_date(?, 'DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date(?, 'DD-MON-YYYY') >=from_date and to_date(?, 'DD-MON-YYYY') <=to_date1 and user_id='112'


org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)



Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3677)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2749)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:494)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:266)
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: there should be a caused by exception in the stack trace, please attach the full stack trace.

Comment: I have attached all logs.

Comment: @hunter: please check i have added new Log(Its invalid column name) ,But i have given valid column

Comment: copy this query and replace all '?' with the parameter values and try to run it directly using your SQL client tool.

Comment: Its working fine in my client SQL tool.    select USER_ID,REASSIGN_TO from tb_bami_vacation  where TO_DATE1 >=TO_DATE('29-Mar-2017' , 'DD-MON-YYYY') and TO_DATE('29-Mar-2017' , 'DD-MON-YYYY') >=from_date and TO_DATE('29-Mar-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY') <=TO_DATE1 and user_id='112'

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: Oracle data base I am using

Comment: i am not familiar with Oracle, but in MS SQL to troubleshoot this kind of problem, what we do is use the SQL profiler  and catch the actual query which is going to be executed against the db. even though for incorrect query , profiler will catch it. if Oracle has that kind mechanism you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'a' from here:

```
from tb_bami_vacation a where
```

Change:

```
@Param("toDate")
```

to:

```
@Param("to_date1")
```

Comment: Still the same exception.Can i remove that 'to_date' because its not a cloumn

Comment: Actually to_date looks like a function which converts date to some comparable format. Another problem you have is that you have to_date1 (please note 1 at the end) which is not defined anywhere. If you have it in your database as column then you should SELECT it because for now you're selecting only 'user_id' and 'reassign_to'. I guess you could alternatively change @Param("toDate") to @Param("to_date1"). Please check my updated answer for better readability.